# Where do I store google api key in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, youtube-api, android-security

Now I'm storing api key in `google-services.json` in (app-level) directory. But when I publish the app google console give the warning **Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this [Google Help Centre](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711?hl=en) article for details.**

Comment: That message almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with google-services.json, if it was placed in the correct location.

Comment: @victory did you ever find a solution to this?